# How to separate two faces?

Tags: mesh

I had problem spearating two faces (planes not cubes) there's probably easy way that I don't know for some reason. Here in the link, there's exactly what I was trying to do.
Thank for any help.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pzIbM.jpg

Comment: Select the edges and hit "V" to rip them.

Comment: [How to upload an image to a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post)